# Error when visiting PHP page, using $_REQUEST

Tags: request, php

```
<?php
if ($_REQUEST['c'] == "1") {
    echo "<p style=\"text-align: center;\">Your shell account has been setup. Please check your inbox.</p>";
}
elseif ($_REQUEST['c'] == "2") {
    echo "<p style=\"color: red; text-align: center;\">There was a problem setting up your account! Please contact Fike via his details <a href=\"http://fike.me\">here</a>.</p>";
}
else {
    include("elements/signup_form.php");
}
```

Could somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong? When I request the normal page, it's supposed to display the form, however it gives me these errors:

`Notice: Undefined index: c in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 27`

`Notice: Undefined index: c in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 30`

Comment: Try using respective method like $_POST or $_GET. Before using please check the variable set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking if `$_REQUEST['c']` exists as well:

```
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['c']) && $_REQUEST['c'] == "1") {
    echo "<p style=\"text-align: center;\">Your shell account has been setup. Please check your inbox.</p>";
}
elseif (isset($_REQUEST['c']) && $_REQUEST['c'] == "2") {
    echo "<p style=\"color: red; text-align: center;\">There was a problem setting up your account! Please contact Fike via his details <a href=\"http://fike.me\">here</a>.</p>";
}
else {
    include("elements/signup_form.php");
}
```

Comment: Ok, your code didn't throw errors, but it still didn't display the form.

Comment: @Fike What is the URL you have used to access the page? Are you expecting a message and the form, or just the form? Try using `require()` instead of `include()` and see if you get another error...

Comment: have you made sure that the form script works on its own?  Maybe put a simple echo into the `else` condition to make sure your code is falling into it when `$_REQUEST['c']` is not set or the wrong value.

Comment: I used http://localhost/ (it's on my home server atm, pushing it to http://shells.fike.me when it's finished). I tried require, still the same.

Comment: Ah, it was working, something happened to the code I had in signup_form.php :/. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

Do this instead:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['c'])) switch ($_REQUEST['c']) {
  case '1':
    echo "<p style=\"text-align: center;\">Your shell account has been setup. Please check your inbox.</p>";
    break;
  case '2':
    echo "<p style=\"color: red; text-align: center;\">There was a problem setting up your account! Please contact Fike via his details <a href=\"http://fike.me\">here</a>.</p>";
    break;
  default:
    require("elements/signup_form.php");
    break;
} else require("elements/signup_form.php");
```

Using `switch` allows you to easily handle unrecognised values of `$_REQUEST['c']` with a `default:` and also makes it easier to add handlers for new values of `$_REQUEST['c']` in the future.

Answer (score 0):

What the error is basically saying is that c is not defined so it can't check if it is 1 or 2, you need to make sure that the variable is set first.

You can do this using the convenient function called 'isset' to work out if the request has been sent. You can read about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php).

```
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['c'] && $_REQUEST['c'] == "1") {
        echo "<p style=\"text-align: center;\">Your shell account has been setup. Please check your inbox.</p>";
}
elseif (isset($_REQUEST['c'] && $_REQUEST['c'] == "2") {
    echo "<p style=\"color: red; text-align: center;\">There was a problem setting up your account! Please contact Fike via his details <a href=\"http://fike.me\">here</a>.</p>";
}
else {
    include("elements/signup_form.php");
}
?>
```

I'm not the best PHP guy but that might work :)

Comment: What happens where `$_REQUEST['c'] = "I am an unexpected value"`?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['c']) && $_REQUEST['c'] === "1")
{
    echo '<p style="text-align: center;">Your shell account has been setup. Please      check your inbox.</p>';
}
else if (isset($_REQUEST['c']) && $_REQUEST['c'] === "2")
{
    echo '<p style="color: red; text-align: center;">There was a problem setting up your account! Please contact Fike via his details <a href="http://fike.me">here</a>.</p>';
}
else 
{
    require 'elements/signup_form.php';
}
```